# Equivalent Line Angle Structures?

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, structural-formula

Are the following equivalent structures for 2,2-dimethylpropane?
[image]

I think so, because my rendering simply rotates the cross 45 degrees!

Also, regarding 3,3-diethylpentane, are these both equally valid structures? My rendering seems to look way different but filling in the carbons and hydrogens, both appear correct:

[image]

Comment: Ah, the swastika molecule …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) yes, those are equivalent structures of 2,2-dimethylpropane

b) yes, those are equivalent structures of 3,3-diethylpentane